# Visibility of members of base template class not directly inherited

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, language-lawyer, using-declaration

The access to members of a template base class requires the syntax `this->member` or the `using` directive. Does this syntax extends also to base template classes which are not directly inherited?

Consider the following code:

```
template <bool X>
struct A {
  int x;
};

template <bool X>
struct B : public A<X> {
  using A<X>::x; // OK even if this is commented out
};

template <bool X>
struct C : public B<X> {
  // using B<X>::x; // OK
  using A<X>::x; // Why OK?
  C() { x = 1; }
};

int main()
{
  C<true> a;

  return 0;
}
```

Since the declaration of the template class `B` contains `using A<X>::x`, naturally the derived template class `C` can access to `x` with a `using B<X>::x`. Nevertheless, on g++ 8.2.1 and clang++ 6.0.1 the above code compiles fine, where `x` is accessed in `C` with a `using` that picks up `x` directly from `A`

I would have expected that `C` can not access directly to `A`. Also, commenting out the `using A<X>::x` in `B` still makes the code to compile. Even the combination of commenting out `using A<X>::x` in `B` and at the same time employ in `C` `using B<X>::x` instead of `using A<X>::x` gives a code that compiles.

Is the code legal?

**Addition**

To be more clear: the question arises on *template* classes and it is about the visibility of members inherited by template classes.
By standard public inheritance, the public members of `A` are accessible to `C`, so using the syntax `this->x` in `C` one does indeed get access to `A<X>::x`. But what about the `using` directive? How does the compiler correctly resolve the `using A<X>::x` if `A<X>` is not a direct base of `C`?

Comment: Why should that be illegal? A deriving class inherits all the members of its base class with the same visibility. There is no differentiation in C++ whether a member of base was defined in base itself or inherited – at least as long as no hiding occurs due to equally named variables in base and derived class, but in this case you might experience other trouble anyway...

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for the comment, I have explained a bit more the question.

Comment: That's a good question. `A<X>` being a base is dependent on `B`. This does indeed raise the question of why one can name `A<X>` as a base freely. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. one up-vote since it made me think twice!

Comment: This is **not about visibility**. It's about whether the member has to exist. For example, you could add `template<> A<false> {};`, which defines an instantiation of `A` that does not have a member named `x`. Saying `A<X>::x` tells the compiler "I expect a member named `x` in `A<X>`, so if you don't find one, stop looking. Otherwise, the compiler would go on looking in outer scopes, eventually finding that global `int x;` and using that, with surprising results.

Comment: @Aconcagua Look up (pun intended): two phase name lookup

Comment: @PeteBecker It's about visibility: how could a compiler know that `x` is in a base class `A` w/o the using declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `A<X>` where a base class is expected.

> **[namespace.udecl]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#3) In a using-declaration used as a member-declaration, each
>   using-declarator's nested-name-specifier shall name a base class of
>   the class being defined.

Since this appears where a class type is expected, it is known and assumed to be a type. And it is a type that is dependent on the template arguments, so it's not looked up immediately.

> **[temp.res]**
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#9) When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template
>   definition, the usual lookup rules ([basic.lookup.unqual],
>   [basic.lookup.argdep]) are used for non-dependent names. The lookup of
>   names dependent on the template parameters is postponed until the
>   actual template argument is known ([temp.dep]).

So it's allowed on account of the compiler not being able to know any better. It will check the using declaration when the class is instantiated. Indeed, one can put any dependent type there:

```
template<bool> struct D{};

template <bool X>
struct C : public B<X> {
  using D<X>::x; 
  C() { x = 1; }
};
```

This will not be checked until the value of `X` is known. Because `B<X>` can bring with it all sorts of surprises if it's specialized. One could for instance do this:

```
template<>
struct D<true> { char x; };

template<>
struct B<true> : D<true> {};
```

Making the above declaration be correct.

Comment: would this also be OK in case of ```C<false> c;``` ?

Comment: @AKL - Using `D`? You'll get an error when instantiating it. The point is that the compiler has no way of knowing if it's correct or not until the instantiation.

Comment: I agree, no further argument! :) Also one up vote for the nice trick!

Comment: "_Since this appears where a class type is expected, it is known and assumed to be a type_" What could `A<T>` ever be except a type?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the code legal?

Yes. This is what public inheritance does.

> Is it possible to allow a template class derived from B to access to x only via this->x, using B::x or B::x? ...

You can use private inheritance (i.e. `struct B : private A<X>`), and arrange access to `A<X>::x` only through `B`'s public/protected interface.

Also, if you're worried about having hidden members, you should use `class` instead of `struct` and specify the desired visibility explicitly.

---

Regarding the addition, note that:

(1) the compiler knows what object `A<X>::x` refers to given some instance of `A<X>` (because `A` is defined in the global scope, and `X` is the template parameter of `C`).

(2)  You do indeed have an instance of `A<X>` - `this` is a ponter to a derived class (it doesn't matter if `A<X>` is a direct base class or not).

(3) The object `A<X>::x` is visible in the current scope (because the inheritances and the object itself are public).

The using statement is merely syntactic sugar. Once all types are resolved, the compiler replaces following use of `x` with the appropriate memory address in the instance, not unlike writing `this->x`  directly.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have explained a little more the question, and removed the second one as not being really relevant for the main question.

Comment: Editted to address your addition

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example could give you some idea as to why should it be legal:

```
template <bool X>
struct A {
  int x;
};

template <bool X>
struct B : public A<X> {
  int x;
};

template <bool X>
struct C : public B<X> {
  //it won't work without this
  using A<X>::x; 
  //or
  //using B<X>::x;
  C() {  x = 1; }
  // or
  //C() { this -> template x = 1; }
  //C() { this -> x = 1; }
};
```

In case of choosing `C() { this -> template x = 1; }` the last inherited `x` (`B::x`) would be assigned to `1` not the `A::x`.

It can simply be tested by:

```
    C<false> a;
    std::cout << a.x    <<std::endl;
    std::cout << a.A::x <<std::endl;
    std::cout << a.B::x <<std::endl;
```

Assuming that the programmer for `struct B` was not aware of `struct A` members, but the programmer of `struct c` was aware of members of both, it seems very reasonable for this feature to be allowed!

As to why should compiler be able to recognize `using A<X>::x;` when it is used in `C<X>` , consider the fact that within the definition of a class/class template all the direct/indirect inherited bases are visible regardless of the type of inheritance. But only the publicly inherited ones are accessible!

For example if it was like:

```
using A<true>::x;
//or
//using B<true>::x;
```

Then there would be a problem by doing:

```
C<false> a;
```

Or wise versa. since neither `A<true>` or `B<true>` is a base for `C<false>`, therefor visible. But since it is like:

```
using A<X>::x;
```

Because the generic term `X` is used in order to define the term `A<X>`, it is first deducible second recognizable, since any `C<X>` (if is not specialized later) is indirectly based on `A<X>` !

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer, the question is more about the visibility, see my edited question.

Comment: `this -> template x`. Why `template`? `x` is not.

Comment: @Jarod42 do you mean why not simply use ```this->x``` ? you are right. that can also be used with same effect without any difference. I have edited my answer accordingly and thanks for the tip.

Comment: I would simply remove `template` `this->x` is enough.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, I have already edited my answer to include it. Is the rest ok?

Answer (score -1):

```
template <bool X>
struct C : public B<X> {
  // using B<X>::x; // OK
  using A<X>::x; // Why OK?
  C() { x = 1; }
};
```

The question is why wouldn't that be supported? Because the constrain that `A<X>` is a base of a specialization of the main template definition of `C` is a question that can only be answered, and that only makes sense for a particular template argument `X`?

*To be able to check templates at definition time was never a design goal of C++*. Many well formed-ness constrains are checked at instanciation time and this is fine.

[Without a true concept (necessary and sufficient template parameter contracts) support no variant of C++ would do significantly better, and C++ is probably too complicated and irregular to have true concepts and true separate checking of templates, ever.]

The principles that makes it necessary to qualify a name to make it dependent does *not* have anything with early diagnostic of errors in template code; the way name lookup works in template **was considered necessary by the designers to support "sane" (actually slightly less insane) name lookup in template code**: a use of a non local name in a template shouldn't bind *too often* to a name declared by the client code, as it would break encapsulation and locality.

Note that for any unqualified dependent name **you can end up accidentally calling an unrelated clashing user function** if it's a better match for overloading resolution, which is another problem that would be fixed by true concept contracts.

Consider this "system" (i.e. not part of current project) header:

```
// useful_lib.hh _________________
#include <basic_tool.hh>

namespace useful_lib {
  template <typename T>
  void foo(T x) { ... }

  template <typename T>
  void bar(T x) { 
    ...foo(x)... // intends to call useful_lib::foo(T)
                 // or basic_tool::foo(T) for specific T
  }
} // useful_lib
```

And that project code:

```
// user_type.hh _________________
struct UserType {};

// use_bar1.cc _________________
#include <useful_lib.hh>
#include "user_type.hh"

void foo(UserType); // unrelated with basic_tool::foo

void use_bar1() {
  bar(UserType()); 
}

// use_bar2.cc _________________
#include <useful_lib.hh>
#include "user_type.hh"

void use_bar2() {
  bar(UserType()); // ends up calling basic_tool::foo(UserType)
}

void foo(UserType) {}
```

I think that code is pretty realistic and reasonable; see if you can see the very serious and non local issue (an issue that can only be found by reading two or more distinct functions).

The issue is caused by the use of an unqualified dependent name in a library template code with a name that isn't documented (intuitivement shouldn't *have* to be) or that is documented but that the user wasn't interested in, as he never needed to override that part of the library behavior.

```
void use_bar1() {
  bar(UserType()); // ends up calling ::foo(UserType)
}
```

That wasn't intended and the user function might have a completely different behavior and fails at runtime. Of course it could also have an incompatible return type and fail for that reason (if the library function returned a value unlike in that example, obviously). Or it could create an ambiguity during overload resolution (more involved case possible if the function takes multiple arguments and both library and user functions are templates).

If this wasn't bad enough, now consider linking use_bar1.cc and use_bar2.cc; now we have two uses of the same template function in different contexts, leading to different expansions (in macro-speak, as templates are only slightly better than glorified macros); unlike preprocessor macros, you are not allowed to do that as the same concrete function `bar(UserType)` is being defined in two different ways by two translation units: *this is an ODR violation, the program is ill formed no diagnostic required*. That means that if the implementation doesn't catch the error at link time (and very few do), the behavior at runtime is undefined from start: no run of the program has defined behavior.

If you are interested, the design of name lookup in template, in the era of the "ARM" (Annotated C++ Reference Manual), long before ISO standardization, is discussed in D&E (Design and Evolution of C++).

Such unintentional binding of a name was avoided at least with qualified names and non dependent names. You can't reproduce that issue with a non dependent unqualified names:

```
namespace useful_lib {
  template <typename T>
  void foo(T x) { ... }

  template <typename T>
  void bar(T x) { 
    ...foo(1)... // intends to call useful_lib::foo<int>(int)
  }
} // useful_lib
```

Here the name binding is done such that no better overload match (that is no match by a non template function) can "beat" the specialization `useful_lib::foo<int>` because the name is bound in the context of the template function definition, and also because `useful_lib::foo` hides any outside name.

Note that without the `useful_lib` namespace, another `foo` that happened to be declared in another header included before could still be found:

```
// some_lib.hh _________________
template <typename T>
void foo(T x) { }

template <typename T>
void bar(T x) { 
  ...foo(1)... // intends to call ::foo<int>(int)
}

// some_other_lib.hh _________________
void foo(int);

// user1.cc _________________
#include <some_lib.hh>
#include <some_other_lib.hh>

void user1() {
  bar(1L);
}

// user2.cc _________________
#include <some_other_lib.hh>
#include <some_lib.hh>

void user2() {
  bar(2L);
}
```

You can see that the only declarative difference between the TUs is the order of inclusion of headers:

- `user1` causes the instanciation of `bar<long>` defined without `foo(int)` visible and name lookup of `foo` only finds the `template <typename T> foo(T)` signature so binding is obviously done to that function template;
- `user2` causes the instanciation of `bar<long>` defined with `foo(int)` visible so name lookup finds both `foo` and the non template one is a better match; the intuitive rule of overloading is that anything (function template or regular function) that can match less argument lists wins: `foo(int)` can only match exactly an `int` while `template <typename T> foo(T)` can match anything (that can be copied).

So again the linking of both TUs causes an ODR violation; the most likely practical behavior is that which function is included in the executable is unpredictable, but an optimizing compiler might assume that the call in `user1()` does not call `foo(int)` and generate a non inline call to `bar<long>` that happens to be the second instanciation that ends up calling `foo(int)`, which might cause incorrect code to be generated [assume `foo(int)` could only recurse through `user1()` and the compiler sees it doesn't recurse and compile it such that recursion is broken (this can be the case if there is a modified static variable in that function and the compiler moves modifications across function calls to fold successive modifications)].

This shows that templates are horribly weak and brittle and should be used with extreme care.

But in your case, there is no such name binding issue, as in that context a using declaration can only name a (direct or indirect) base class. It doesn't matter that the compiler cannot know at definition time whether it's a direct or indirect base or an error; it will check that in due time.

While early diagnostic of inherently erroneous code is permitted (because `sizeof(T())` is exactly the same as `sizeof(T)`, the declared type of `s` is illegal in any instantiation):

```
template <typename T>
void foo() { // template definition is ill formed
  int s[sizeof(T) - sizeof(T())]; // ill formed
}
```

diagnosing that at template definition time is not practically important and not required for conforming compilers (and I don't believe compiler writers try to do it).

**Diagnostic only at the point of instantiation of issues that are guaranteed to be caught at that point is fine; it does not break any design goal of C++.**